# Neon bindings example with RefCell not working

Tags: rust, neon-bindings

I'm trying to figure out how to use native Rust modules in NodeJS using the Neon crate. To get started I was following an example using `RefCell` to make it possible to call `mut` functions on an object through JavaScript.

However, when I copy the example code, it doesn't compile. It says `Cannot borrow immutable local variable 'person' as mutable` & `no method named 'set_name' found for mutable reference '&mut neon::handle::Handle<'_, neon::prelude::JsBox<std::cell::RefCell<Person>>>' in the current scope` (positions given in comments in the code below)

I really need this kind of functionality in my app, because it needs some engine running in the background, controlled via JS. Any hints are appreciated.

It's about the following code ([source](https://docs.rs/neon/0.7.1-napi/neon/types/struct.JsBox.html)):

```rust
type BoxedPerson = JsBox<RefCell<Person>>;

struct Person {
     name: String,
}

impl Finalize for Person {}

impl Person {
    pub fn new(name: String) -> Self {
        Person { name }
    }
 
    pub fn set_name(&mut self, name: String) {
        self.name = name;
    }
 
    pub fn greet(&self) -> String {
        format!("Hello, {}!", self.name)
    }
}
 
fn person_new(mut cx: FunctionContext) -> JsResult<BoxedPerson> {
    let name = cx.argument::<JsString>(0)?.value(&mut cx);
    let person = RefCell::new(Person::new(name));
 
    Ok(cx.boxed(person))
}
 
fn person_set_name(mut cx: FunctionContext) -> JsResult<JsUndefined> {
    let person = cx.argument::<BoxedPerson>(0)?;

    // Cannot borrow immutable local variable 'person' as mutable
    let mut person = person.borrow_mut();
    let name = cx.argument::<JsString>(1)?.value(&mut cx);
 
    // no method named `set_name` found for mutable reference 
    // `&mut neon::handle::Handle<'_, neon::prelude::JsBox<std::cell::RefCell<Person>>>` 
    // in the current scope
    person.set_name(name);
 
    Ok(cx.undefined())
}
 
fn person_greet(mut cx: FunctionContext) -> JsResult<JsString> {
    let person = cx.argument::<BoxedPerson>(0)?;
    let person = person.borrow();
    let greeting = person.greet();
 
    Ok(cx.string(greeting))
}
```

Comment: What version of Rust are you using? I tried that code locally on 1.62.0-nightly and it compiled fine. What seems to be happening is it's resolving the call to `borrow_mut` to `BorrowMut<Handle<'_, BoxedPerson>>::borrow_mut` instead of doing a deref and then calling `borrow_mut` on the `RefCell`.

Comment: I was on 1.57, just upgraded to 1.60. Still the same problem however...

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around it by doing the following:

```rust
fn person_set_name(mut cx: FunctionContext) -> JsResult<JsUndefined> {
    let person = cx.argument::<BoxedPerson>(0)?;

    let person = &*(*person);
    let mut person = person.borrow_mut();

    let name = cx.argument::<JsString>(1)?.value(&mut cx);
    person.borrow_mut().set_name(name);

    Ok(cx.undefined())
}
```